# How to convert url into filename?

Tags: c#, .net, url, converters, filenames

I want to convert an aribtrary url, including path and query parts, into a valid filename. I've chosen to use `Base64` as shown below.

Is there a better Base64 code such as avoiding `Byte[]`? What is best practice for url to filename? I suppose there's an issue with exceeding filename length limit.

```
string encoded = 
   System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(url));
string decoded = 
   System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(encoded));

if (decoded != url)
    throw(new SomeException());
```

Comment: Should the file name still be human-readable/understandable? Do you still need to be able to turn it back into the original Url?

Comment: For initial development, the need is to cache an API's returned JSON for caching, offline use. The URLs are always the same each time. I don't need human readable but I do need to convert filename back to url.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the best practice is that if possible, the filename hould not have a direct relation with the URL. Unless you control the URL's with which this method will be called, you open yourself upon to a security danger. It would be best if you could generate some local ID, use that as the filename and then link that ID to the URL. That way you are always completely in control on what filenames are being written, whereas using the URL opens you up to potential attackers.

Comment: What security dangers are you anticipating? I'm assuming that the conversion will prevent files being called `"../../../windows/[...]"` and past that I can't see much security issue. I've certainly used utilities like `wget` which can download web pages into folder structures mirroring the url and have not heard of any security problems related to that...

Comment: @Erik, I do control the URLs.

Comment: @Chris, longer term, yes, I do want code that does what wget does. Code?

Comment: @BSalita If you do control the URL's, I guess a convenient method would be to use the full URL string and then use its `GetHashCode()` method for an identifier.

Comment: @Erik, GetHashCode() might work if the lifecycle of the filename is a process. Otherwise it isn't guaranteed between executions.

Comment: @BSalita If you need it between executions, you could resort to a hash algorithm like MD5.

Comment: @Erik, can't roundtrip MD5.

Answer (score 1):

If/when you need to translate the name back to the original Url you might want to create a separate mapping table. Generate a unique file name and store it in the table with the original Url next to it. You could use an API (Guid, Random, DateTime) or a simple counter to get a unique file name.

This way do do not have to worry about duplicates and illegal characters because you are in control of the file name generation.

As you are caching JSON request/responses be care full with POSTs: the urls of two requests might be the same but the contents might be different so you might not want to use the cache for the first one for the next.

In general you wouldn't cache POST's but some REST APIs use POSTs to bypass the maximum Url GET request length.

Comment: Erno, good point about POSTs. In my situation, it's always a GET.